# BOOST_FOREACH: is there a trick to avoid the all-caps spelling?

Tags: c++, boost

BOOST_FOREACH is really neat, but the C macro style of writing is somewhat off-putting. 
Is there a trick to avoid the all-caps spelling?

Comment: I think this is a BAD idea. BOOST_FOREACH is in ALL CAPS because it's a MACRO. MARCOs are dangerous enough, and there it is somewhat conventional to make 'em CAPS so people can recognize them.

This way you won't be tempted to write things like

boost_foreach(int a, do_crazy_stuff_to_get_an_array()){
}

cliffs:
it's uppercase for convention.

Comment: From the documentation: "And although BOOST_FOREACH is a macro, it is a remarkably well-behaved one. It evaluates its arguments exactly once, leading to no nasty surprises"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actually, a little more googling and reading revealed the answer right in the [Boost foreach documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/foreach.html):

> **Making BOOST_FOREACH Prettier**
>
> People have complained about the name
>   BOOST_FOREACH. It's too long. ALL CAPS
>   can get tiresome to look at. That may
>   be true, but BOOST_FOREACH is merely
>   following the Boost Naming Convention.
>   That doesn't mean you're stuck with
>   it, though. If you would like to use a
>   different identifier (foreach,
>   perhaps), you can simply do:
>
> `#define foreach         BOOST_FOREACH`
>   `#define reverse_foreach BOOST_REVERSE_FOREACH`
>
> Only do this if you are sure that the
>   identifier you choose will not cause
>   name conflicts in your code.

and with that I just opted for

```
// cf http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/foreach.html 
// -- Making BOOST_FOREACH Prettier
#define boostForeach  BOOST_FOREACH
```

Answer (score 30):

Perhaps this?

```
#define foreach BOOST_FOREACH
```